# Anonymous methods and with some constant arguments

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

I have a function `FUNC1(int a)` and a function `FUNC2(int a, int b)`. I have a delegate with a type of `void()` (no arguments). I want to have 2 variables. When I call one like this: `VAR1()` then `FUNC1(4)` will run. and `VAR2` that will run `FUNC2(2,9)`. I asked this yesterday, and I was told to use anonymous methods like this: `VAR1 = () => FUNC1(4)` and it works fine.

Now I want to do something a little more complicated. I have a new type of delegate `void(int a)`. and I want a variable `VAR3`. When I call `VAR3(5)` I want to execute `FUNC2(5,8)`. If I call `VAR3(9)` I want to execute `FUNC2(9,8)`. So basically, the first argument can change, but the second argument is constant.

Comment: Sounds like you need `VAR3 = (i)=> FUNC2(i, 8);` Btw your question is hard to understand. Adding some code will make it better.

Comment: I think you should learn the basics about how to use delegates and anonymous methods. You could start here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that woulde be something like that:

```
VAR3 = (x)=>FUNC2(x,8);
```